# Access property of React component based on another property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Ultimately I am trying to create a piano like application that you can control by click or key down. I want each keyboard key to control a certain note. Each "piano" key is a component which has a keycode property and a note property. When the event.keycode matches the keycode property I want the associated note to play. What is the best strategy to go about this?

I have tried using refs and playing around with focus on componentDidMount. I cant seem to wrap my head around how this should work.

```
class Pad extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            clicked: false
        }

        this.clickedMouse = this.clickedMouse.bind(this)
        this.unClickedMouse = this.unClickedMouse.bind(this)
        this.handleDownKeyPress = this.handleDownKeyPress.bind(this)
        this.handleUpKeyPress = this.handleUpKeyPress.bind(this)
    }

    clickedMouse(e) {
        this.setState({ clicked: true })
        this.props.onDown(this.props.note)
        console.log(e)
    }

    unClickedMouse(e) {
        this.setState({ clicked: false })
        this.props.onUp(this.props.note)
    }

    handleDownKeyPress(e) {

        if (e.keyCode === this.props.keyCode && this.state.clicked === false) {
            this.setState({ clicked: true })
            this.props.onDown(this.props.note)
        }
    }

    handleUpKeyPress(e) {
        this.setState({ clicked: false })
        this.props.onUp(this.props.note)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div
                className='pad'
                onMouseUp={this.unClickedMouse}
                onMouseDown={this.clickedMouse}
                onKeyDown={this.handleDownKeyPress}
                onKeyUp={this.handleUpKeyPress}
                tabIndex='0'
            />
        );
    }
}

export default Pad

class Pads extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // tone.js build
        this.synth = new Tone.Synth().toMaster()
        this.vol = new Tone.Volume(0)
        this.synth.chain(this.vol, Tone.Master)

        // bindings
        this.onDownKey = this.onDownKey.bind(this);
        this.onUpKey = this.onUpKey.bind(this);
    }

    onDownKey(note) {
        console.log(`${note} played`);
        this.synth.triggerAttack(note);
    }

    onUpKey(note) {
        this.synth.triggerRelease();
    }

    render() {
        const { octave } = this.props
        return (
            <div className="pad-grid">
                <Pad
                    keyCode={65}
                    note={`C${octave}`}
                    onDown={this.onDownKey}
                    onUp={this.onUpKey}
                />
                <Pad
                    keyCode={70}
                    note={`Db${octave}`}
                    onDown={this.onDownKey}
                    onUp={this.onUpKey}
                />
                <Pad
                    keyCode={83}
                    note={`D${octave}`}
                    onDown={this.onDownKey}
                    onUp={this.onUpKey}
                />
                <Pad
                    keyCode={68}
                    note={`Eb${octave}`}
                    onDown={this.onDownKey}
                    onUp={this.onUpKey}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Pads
```

Heres a codepen so you can check it out in action https://codepen.io/P-FVNK/pen/XopBgW

Comment: The codepen works with clicks, does any part of it work with keyboard input as you've requested?

Comment: @KenoClayton After you click a square you can then use the key mapped to that square but none of the other key mapping will work. For example, click the first square and press your A key, then click second square and press your F key. When the page renders I want to have access to all the keyCode properties. Is there a way to maybe loop through the repeated components and their properties to match event.keyCode to correct keycode property? Thanks for your response!

Comment: Just saw your reply, and yes you could have them set from the first render of the page. I'll try to provide an example soon

Comment: I created a codesandbox with the updated code which you can check out here: https://codesandbox.io/s/5v89kw6w0n. Still updating it, will post an answer once I've tweaked it all. 

Basically I'm assigning a keyup/down listener to the document instead of the individual pads. Also I'm adding pads to the state and rendering that array instead of writing each one out. You can see their data in the `this.padCodes` object.

This makes it a lot cleaner and easier to expand as needed.

Comment: @KenoClayton WOW thank you so much! I have been trying to figure this out for days!! I never thought about going about it like that but it makes so much sense now. Thanks again!!

Comment: Posted an answer, you can review it and mark it as the answer if it helped you resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/5v89kw6w0n

So I made quite a number of changes to enable the functionality you wanted.

> Is there a way to maybe loop through the repeated components and their properties to match event.keyCode to correct keycode property?

To enable this, I decided to create an object array containing the possible keys and their notes. I changed them from the now deprecated [`KeyboardEvent.keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) to [`KeyboardEvent.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead. You could use [`KeyboardEvent.code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) as well.

```js
this.padCodes = [
  {
    key: "a",
    note: "C"
  },
  {
    key: "f",
    note: "Db"
  },
  {
    key: "s",
    note: "D"
  },
  {
    key: "d",
    note: "Eb"
  }
];
```

I moved the `keydown` event listeners from the individual `<Pad />`s to the parent component and attached the listener to the document instead.

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
  let index = this.state.pads.findIndex(item => item.key === e.key);
  let { octave } = this.context;
  if (this.state.pressed === false) {
    this.onDownKey(`${this.state.pads[index].props.note}${octave}`);
    this.setState({
      activeNote: this.state.pads[index].note,
      pressed: true
    });
  }
});
document.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  this.onUpKey(this.state.activeNote);
  this.setState({
    activeNote: "",
    pressed: false
  });
});
```

You may also notice I decided to use the [`Context`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) instead of props. That's just personal preference, but I rather have one main reference to the octave state rather than passing the prop to each child component.

After that it was just a matter of ensuring that the functions made the calls to the same function and passed both the note and octave.

To reduce some of the clutter I made an array of `<Pad />`s which I later rendered instead of typing them out one by one.

```js
let newPadCodes = this.padCodes.map(x => (
    <Pad
      key={x.key.toString()}
      note={`${x.note}`}
      onDown={this.onDownKey}
      onUp={this.onUpKey}
    />
));

this.setState({
  pads: newPads
});

//And later

//Render if this.state.pads.length is > 0
{this.state.pads.length > 0 &&
 this.state.pads}
```

That just about covers all I did. Here's the codesandbox with the modified code: https://codesandbox.io/s/5v89kw6w0n